# Number of OSCP certificate holders?

Tags: oscp

This might be a duplicate question.Given that OSCP has a reputation as hard to pass, does anyone have an idea of the number of people that cleared the OSCP certification course and lab examination?

Answer (score 1):

Offensive Security refuses to give details on the number of their certificates' holders or on the passing rate as they "don't want to unnecessarily encourage or discourage people"

Comment: I found 5315 results for searching 'OSCP' on LInkedIn.

Comment: ...and as of July 2020 there are over 15,000 results on LinkedIn.